# Suggestion on design approach for replacing DataTables with Generic Collections ( C# + Winforms )

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, generics, datatable, devexpress

In our application we have been using Datatables as a DataSource for all of the Data Container controls. These are Win Form Grid. But now we have decided to move away from DataTables and start using Object based Generic .Net collections. And the reason of shift is, We use DevExpress Controls and we want to utilize ServerMode option provided by Data Grid, which actually works on Collection of Objects. Below are the important things which we need to implement in Collections :

1. Primary Key feature provided by DataTable, we need to figure out the approach to maintain the same in Generic Collections.
2. DataTable.Merge functionality is required,I know Enumerable.Union can be used, but want to ask is there any other efficient way of merging to collections based on few members from the objects acting as Primary Key.
3. DataRelations : How to maintain DataRelation kind of feature in Collections.
4. Any other limitation or design caution which we need to take care in this shift.

I have already gone through the question [Best c# generics class for replacing DataTable as collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380067/best-c-sharp-generics-class-for-replacing-datatable-as-collection)

But It was not sufficient for my case, so asking a new question.

Please suggest or point me to some code samples/ KB articles for reference.

Update #1 :

This question has some pointers for Key Based Merging of collections :
[Merge two list with based on key c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988140/merge-two-list-with-based-on-key-c-sharp?rq=1)

But I am not sure about the performance with this approach, as I am looking at 500K+ records in end collection to display on the GUI.

Update #2:

Enumerable.Union will not be useful in my scenario.Because by Merge of two Collections what I mean is  :

If I have

```
List<Student> mainList 
List<Student> newList
```

where

```
Student.RollNo
```

Will be using

```
IComparable on Student class comparing RollNo for two Student objects.
```

should be Primary Key. The merge should result as :

1. All new Students from newList should be added to mainList.
2. If a Student is already there in mainList and also in newList then always Student from newList should override and old one should be removed and new one should be added.
3. Is there any way to specify any member from Student Class as Primary Key dynamically based on some XML configs, using Property Attributes or something similar and to use the same in :

   **IComparable.Compare**

I would like to avoid List.Find and List.Replace, if there is any other efficient way of achieving this.